# Styling datepicker: highlight specific dates

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, datepicker

I know that this question has been asked before that the 'solutions' i found so far don't seem to work.

I am using the Contact Form 7 and datepicker plugin on my wordpress website. The contact form and the calendar work just fine but I wanna be able to highlight specific dates by changing the background color of those dates.

Here's the code that I have included in my header file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var SelectedDates = {};
    SelectedDates[new Date('07/26/2016')] = new Date('07/26/2016');
    $('#datepicker123').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
        if (Highlight) {
          return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
        }
        else {
          return [true, '', ''];
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

In my style.css sheet, I have included the following code to add the styling to those dates:

```
.Highlighted a{
   background-color : #1AAFFF !important;
}
```

However, the date in this example (7/26/2016) does not get highlighted when I click on the calendar but the standard styling appears. Where's my mistake?

Many thanks for your help!

Edit: The HTML code seemed super long so here's the link to the website: [KYTE](http://www.kyte-aero.de/anfragen/)

Edit 2: So i've added the following code to my functions.php file:

```
function wpse_enqueue_datepicker() {
  // Load the datepicker script (pre-registered in WordPress).
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );

  // You need styling for the datepicker.
  // For simplicity I've linked to Google's hosted jQuery UI CSS.
  wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );  
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_datepicker' );
```

still not working.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, can you show us the HTML code of your Datepicker? You can right click on the Datepicker, then `Inspect Element` and copy the HTML code.

Comment: Thank you Pascal. I looked at the HTML code and it seemed far too long to post it here, so i've added a link to my site. hope this is fine but please let me know if not

Comment: datepicker is not a function, prettyphoto is not a function....

Comment: Yes, I saw that too (nevermind the prettyphoto bit, that's some old code i still need to take out). But how come this is so? Is it because the wordpress datapicker plugin uses a different function name?

Comment: I've added the ID name ('ui-datepicker-div') of the actual calendar that pops up upon clicking it to the code above but it sill isn't working :/ sorry, i'm completely new to jscript so these are all shots in the dark

Answer (score 0):

I Think you are not setting a highlighted class to selected date  .
try

```
$('td').on('click', function(){
    $('td.Highlighted').removeClass('Highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('Highlighted');
});
```

this will help you
and change your css :

```
tr.Highlighted {
     background-color:red;
}
```

I'v tested it

Comment: Thank you Kavian. Tried your approach but still no luck

Comment: I'm afraid it does not. The problem is that datepicker is not recognized as a function: $(...).datepicker is not a function
(index):424 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).prettyPhoto is not a function.  I think the problem is with the plugin. somewhere the datepicker function gets defined and I need to figure out where so that i can add the date array and showbeforedate function to that.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to call a datepiker method before its library get load.

Try to put this code inside your `functions.php` file

```
<?php
  add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_custom_js');
  function my_custom_js(){

   //Your js code goes here

  }
?>
```

Comment: I tried adding it to the functions.php file (see code above in my original file), but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was puzzled myself and confused until I put my scripts into the footer. Then it worked. I have separate js and css which helps to enqueue them only when needed.

```
function se_3852702_init() {
  // Place your own script in footer (see the last TRUE)
  wp_register_script( 'se_3852702',
    plugins_url( 'se_3852702' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'se_3852702.js',
    [ 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ],
    FALSE,
    TRUE // <======== Place in the footer
  );

  wp_register_style( 'se_3852702', plugins_url( 'se_3852702' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'se_3852702.css' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'se_3852702_init' );

function se_38527021_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'se_3852702' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'se_3852702' );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' );
}
// This is overkill as it always enqueue the scripts.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_38527021_enqueue_scripts' );
```

together with a similar js script

```
jQuery(document).ready(
  (function ($) {
    function dayAvailable(date) {
      console.log(date);
      let day = date.getDate();
      return [day % 2 == 0, 'my-class', 'Label when hover'];
  }

  $('#date-picker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: dayAvailable,
  })
})(jQuery)
);
```

resulting into

[image: Wordpress datepicker]